# Python MergeSort not sorting correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, mergesort

I am trying to implement python Merge Sort, but for some reason when merging it does not sort it correctly at all. I am trying to turn Pseudo code into Python code and I am failing miserably. If anyone can help, I'd really appreciate it. I have tried to debug it and I am just confused.

```
def mergeSort(A, p, r):
    if p < r:
        q = int(((p + (r-1)) / 2))
        mergeSort(A, p, q)
        mergeSort(A, q + 1, r)
        merge(A, p, q, r)

def merge(A, p, q, r): # Issue with sorting
    n1 = q - p + 1
    n2 = r - q
    L = [0] * n1
    R = [0] * n2
    for i in range(0, n1):
        L[i] = A[p + i]
    for j in range(0, n2):
        R[j] = A[q + j]
    L.append(infinity)
    R.append(infinity)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    for k in range(p,r):
        if L[i] <= R[j]:
            A[k] = L[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j = j + 1
```

Example Input:

> ['date', 'apple', 'banana', 'cucumber', 'acorn', 'aaaa']

Example Output:

> ['banana', 'acorn', 'aaaa', 'cucumber', 'date', 'date']

[mergeSort psuedocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gfpu6.png)

[merge pseudocode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpJtb.png)

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and [mre], and study the code carefully. We do not provide a debugging service. Try to make sure you understand what should happen at each step, and check what actually does happen instead. If you believe the problem is in `merge`, then figure out example input, expected and actual output for *just the merge*; then break it down into parts and check *those*.

Comment: Also, consider using more descriptive variable names. Remember, the code is read many more times than it is written, and it especially will be read by **you**.

Answer (score -2):

The issue with your implementation is that you are not properly updating the indices when merging the two sublists back together. In the following lines:

```
for k in range(p,r):
if L[i] <= R[j]:
    A[k] = L[i]
    i = i + 1
else:
    A[k] = R[j]
    j = j + 1
```

you should be incrementing k instead of i and j. Also the condition inside of the if statement should be L[i] <= R[j] instead of L[i] >= R[j].

Here is the corrected version of the merge function:

```
def merge(A, p, q, r):
n1 = q - p + 1
n2 = r - q
L = [0] * n1
R = [0] * n2
for i in range(0, n1):
    L[i] = A[p + i]
for j in range(0, n2):
    R[j] = A[q + j]
i = 0
j = 0
k = p
while i < n1 and j < n2:
    if L[i] <= R[j]:
        A[k] = L[i]
        i += 1
    else:
        A[k] = R[j]
        j += 1
    k += 1
while i < n1:
    A[k] = L[i]
    i += 1
    k += 1
while j < n2:
    A[k] = R[j]
    j += 1
    k += 1
```

Also, you have to import the math library and use math.inf instead of infinity.